# Viewing Linq Queries Output

Tags: c#

I am trying to debug a linq query.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(file);

IEnumerable<String> output = lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(
                                 new[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

String[] stringArray = output.ToArray(); // ERROR HERE
```

Everytime I convert output to array it says reader is closed which I think ReadLines functions close the reader automatically. How can I view the contents of the output variable?

Comment: How are you "outputting" the contents? As is, you should be able to see the results no matter what. Subsequent reads will reopen and reprocess the file but it will still "work".

Comment: Please give more details about how you "convert output to array" and the exact exception you are seeing.

Comment: I updated the question with the line that causes the issue.

Comment: @johndoe That's half of the request.  Now let's see the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can View the content IEnumerable by converting it to List or Array

```
IEnumerable<String> output = 
                lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();

            IEnumerable<String> output = 
                lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

**Update**

Or you can view the result from the Autos Menu "On debugging" by Opening Result View

[image]

Comment: If he wasn't iterating the results of the query he wouldn't be getting file IO errors that he's describing, so clearly that's already happening somewhere.

Comment: How is this any different than what is being done in the question? Why should that matter? Granted, he didn't initally include the `ToArray()` part in the question, how is this supposed to solve anything?

Comment: The question updated and the line "String[] stringArray = output.ToArray(); // ERROR HERE " was not included in the question!.....